# JavaScript: option hiding code not working in some browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

My JavaScript skills are pretty basic, but I've written [this](http://filestore.c1.biz/js/select1.htm) code where you select from the dropdown on the left (Select1) an option which shows only the specified options in the dropdown on the right (Select2), and hides the rest.
I've also put it in a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Tel7/pen/MWmzPjR?editors=1010s), in case you want to fiddle.
The code seems to work in both of the above environments in Firefox 90.0.2, but it fails in both and writes nothing to the console in Chrome 92.0.4515.131.

Any ideas why it's working in Firefox but not Chrome (and others) and what I can do so it works on all major browsers.

I'm running Windows 10 and I'd like to avoid iQuery if practical, as I don't want to get into learning or using that yet, as I'm starting with the basics.

Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function hide_options(select_id,type)
    {
      //alert("hide_options(select_id="+select_id+", type="+type+")");
      console.log("hide_options(select_id="+select_id+", type="+type+")");
      var x = document.getElementById(select_id);
      for (i=1; i<x.options.length; i++)
      {
        x.options[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      x.options[0].selected = true;
      if (type == 'A')
      { unhide_options(select_id,"one","two") }
      if (type == 'B')
      { unhide_options(select_id,"two","three") }
      if (type == 'C')
      { unhide_options(select_id,"two") }
    }
   
    function unhide_options(select_id,...opts)
    {
      //alert("unhide_options(select_id="+select_id+"opts="+opts+")");
      console.log("unhide_options(select_id="+select_id+"opts="+opts+")");
      for (i=0; i<opts.length; i++)
      {
        document.getElementById(select_id+"_"+opts[i]).style.display = "";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Selecting an option in the "Select1" dropdown should show only those options in the "Select2" dropdown.</p>
  <select name=select1>
    <option>Select1...</option>
    <option onclick="hide_options('field1','A')">Show options 1 + 2 only</option>
    <option onclick="hide_options('field1','B')">Show options 2 + 3 only</option>
    <option onclick="hide_options('field1','C')">Show option 2 only</option>
  </select>
    
  <select name=update_action id=field1>
    <option value=''>Select2...</option>
    <option value=one id=field1_one>One</option>
    <option value=two id=field1_two>Two</option>
    <option value=three id=field1_three>Three</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: most likely issue is that chrome doesn't run `onclick` when an `<option>` is clicked - have you tried console.log's inside `hide_options` function?

Comment: add a `change` handler to the `select`, and rewrite your function to account for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Chrome doesn't emit an event on clicking an option - however, you can use the `change` event on the `select`

I've used `data-*` attributes for the options, and I also show/hide in the one loop

the `showing` object is just a nice easy way to configure what should show, so you don't need `if/else if/else if` etc - I find this easier to maintain then countless `if` else if`'s

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('.filterer');
const showing = {
  A: ["one", "two"],
  B: ["two", "three"],
  C: ["two"]
};
selects.forEach(select => {
  select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    const {
      target,
      value
    } = this[this.selectedIndex].dataset;
    const show = showing[value] || [];
    const x = document.getElementById(target) || [];
    [...x]
    .slice(1)
      .forEach(option =>
        option.style.display = (show.length === 0 || show.includes(option.value)) ? '' : 'none'
      );
    if (x && x[0]) {
      x[0].selected = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<p>Selecting an option in the "Select1" dropdown should show only those options in the "Select2" dropdown.</p>
<select id="select1" name="select1" class="filterer">
  <option>Select1...</option>
  <option data-target='field1' data-value='A'>Show options 1 + 2 only</option>
  <option data-target='field1' data-value='B'>Show options 2 + 3 only</option>
  <option data-target='field1' data-value='C'>Show option 2 only</option>
</select>

<select name=update_action id=field1>
  <option value=''>Select2...</option>
  <option value=one id=field1_one>One</option>
  <option value=two id=field1_two>Two</option>
  <option value=three id=field1_three>Three</option>
</select>
<br/>
<hr/>
<select id="select2" name="select2" class="filterer">
  <option>Select1...</option>
  <option data-target='field2' data-value='A'>Show options 1 + 2 only</option>
  <option data-target='field2' data-value='B'>Show options 2 + 3 only</option>
  <option data-target='field2' data-value='C'>Show option 2 only</option>
</select>

<select name=update_action id=field2>
  <option value=''>Select2...</option>
  <option value=one id=field2_one>One</option>
  <option value=two id=field2_two>Two</option>
  <option value=three id=field2_three>Three</option>
</select>
```

Alternative. You mention in a comment that the Selects and Options are created dynamically on the server code

The following would allow you to do that, and to specify the visible selections given the current choice, all in the `option` data-values attribute

Nothing needs hard coding in javascript this way

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('.filterer');
selects.forEach(select => {
  select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    const { target, values } = this[this.selectedIndex].dataset;
    const show = values.split(',').map(s => s.trim());
    const x = document.getElementById(target) || [];
    [...x]
    .slice(1)
      .forEach(option =>
        option.style.display = (show.length === 0 || show.includes(option.value)) ? '' : 'none'
      );
    if (x && x[0]) {
      x[0].selected = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<p>Selecting an option in the "Select1" dropdown should show only those options in the "Select2" dropdown.</p>
<select id="select1" name="select1" class="filterer">
  <option>Select1...</option>
  <option data-target='field1' data-values='one, two'>Show options 1 + 2 only</option>
  <option data-target='field1' data-values='two, three'>Show options 2 + 3 only</option>
  <option data-target='field1' data-values='two'>Show option 2 only</option>
</select>

<select name='update_action' id='field1'>
  <option value=''>Select2...</option>
  <option value='one' id='field1_one'>One</option>
  <option value='two' id='field1_two'>Two</option>
  <option value='three' id='field1_three'>Three</option>
</select>
<br/>
<hr/>
<br/>
<select id="select2" name="select2" class="filterer">
  <option>Select1...</option>
  <option data-target='field2' data-values='apple,banana'>Apple and banana</option>
  <option data-target='field2' data-values='banana,pineapple'>Banana and pineapple</option>
  <option data-target='field2' data-values='pineapple'>Pineapple</option>
</select>

<select name='update_action' id='field2'>
  <option value=''>Select2...</option>
  <option value='pineapple' id='field2_one'>Pineapple</option>
  <option value='banana' id='field2_two'>Banana</option>
  <option value='apple' id='field2_three'>Apple</option>
</select>
```

Sure, this may require changing server code, but your original code did have hard coded logic for `A` `B` and `C` - this code, the server code can emit anything it likes and the javascript doesn't need to be changed

Comment: @dmd - I've long since learned that minimal code here is never truly representative ... sure, you can just use `value="A"` ... and not even need to have the `data-target` ... but why does the original code have a `target`? What I hope I've shown here is how to add it to existing HTML that may already have a `value`, and may have `options` that effect different `select` elements

Comment: @dMd - you're right about `if (x)` ... should be `if (x && x[0])`

Comment: Nice work, thanks Bravo!  (Or should I say, bravo, Bravo!?)  I like the 'showing' object.  And now for the bad news, SORRY!  I'm guessing this would be a bad time to say this is a cut down version from my original code, which could have dozens of pairs of <select> tags depending on the input file, so there'd be field1, field2, ...etc.  Continued in next comment...

Comment: My Perl code dynamically generates the necessary pairs of <select> tags, but with your solution I'd also have to get it to dynamically create the JS code (since it has things like "field1" hardcoded), and I don't do that anywhere else in my application, and which I'd rather avoid if possible.  Any suggestions for solutions which have static JS code?

Comment: @terry, you do have hard coded code for condition A B C in a function - in fact, my original code had just as much "hard coding" as your question - so my edit has made it less flexible in many ways not sure how your actual code relates to the code you posted

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Works beautifully, Bravo.  However, would this be a bad time to say, yes, the A, B, C stuff was hard coded in JS and I'd prefer to leave it that way, because those options are common for all right-hand <select>s.  Sorry, again!  (I'm not usually this bad with scope creap, honest, I just didn't realise my change request was amiguous.)  So I assume if you can somehow bring your "showing" object back into the JS, that would be good.

Comment: well, that makes the code really easy - that's basically just the first version of the first code - I'll revert it

Comment: OK, but you're still going to refer to the A, B, C in the HTML, right?

Comment: Does the first code make sense now @Terry? because the `showing` object simply does exactly what the `if/else if/else if` does in your code

Comment: It looks like the style of thing I'm after, and the executable code snippet is working as it should on this site.  Any ideas why it doesn't work here: http://filestore.c1.biz/js/select2.htm

Comment: because your script is running before the DOM is loading - either move the script to the bottom of `body` or wrap the script in a `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { script here })`

Comment: Thank you so much, Bravo!  Both of those methods to fix the issue of the script running too early work, as demonstrated here: http://filestore.c1.biz/js/select2a.htm and here: http://filestore.c1.biz/js/select2b.htm, so please take a pay rise!